# Problems when update AMP cache

Tags: amp-html

According to the [Update AMP Cache](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache), a URL with in

`https://example-com.<cache.updateCacheApiDomainSuffix>/update-cache/c/s/example.com/article?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=<ts_val>&amp_url_signature=<sig_val>`

form should be generated. It uses a question mark `?` symbol to separate the path and parameter behind `example.com/article?amp_action=`

Now I want to update a url

```
https://m.discuss.com.hk/amp_viewthread.php?tid=24025060.
```

It has a question mark at the end of the URL. Thus, how to construct the URL here?

Should I generate it as:

```
…update-cache/c/s/m.discuss.com.hk/amp_viewthread.php?tid=24025060&amp_action=flush…
```

Or something like:

```
…update-cache/c/s/m.discuss.com.hk/amp_viewthread.php%3ftid=24025060?amp_action=flush…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use URL query string parameters in the AMP URL, see 
https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#query-parameter-example

You should be able to mix your original query parameters in with the update-cache parameters. Check the github discussion [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10883)

So your update url will be

```
…update-cache/c/s/m.discuss.com.hk/amp_viewthread.php?tid=24025060&amp_action=flush…
```

Comment: Many thanks! I think this is the right solution and it works well now.